# Only allow pagebreaks in longtable at rules

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I have a `longtable` with groups of rows that are separated by `\midrule`s. I want to forbid page breaking inside these groups, i.e. have every `\\` behave like `\\*` (without writing the asterisk).

I have tried saying `\global\let\asdf\\ \gdef\\{\asdf*}`, but that fails for reasons not entirely clear to me.

How can I make `\\` behave like `\\*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could exchange in the internal command the arguments of \@ifstar then `\\` will be the unbreakable and `\\*` the breakable variant:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\LT@tabularcr{%
  \relax\iffalse{\fi\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \@ifstar
    {\LT@t@bularcr}
    {\def\crcr{\LT@crcr\noalign{\nobreak}}\let\cr\crcr
     \LT@t@bularcr}%
    }
   \makeatother
   \textheight=20pt %for test
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l}
a\\a\\*a\\a\\\midrule a\\a\\a\\a
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```